# getting the id number from another field

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im new to Access and need a little help

I have a form with a row view in the subform (all fields are not enabled), I want to make the line clickable e.g

```
Private Sub ID_Click()
    recordID = Me.ID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Clients", , , "ID = " & recordID
End Sub

Private Sub Title_Click()
    recordID = Me.ID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Clients", , , "ID = " & recordID
End Sub
```

if the user clicks the id on the row it goes to that record - but clicking on the title field does not, is there a way to get the title field to do the same

Thank any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use the ONCurrent event to grab the ID